# Change value of angular scope when buttons are clicked

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I have multiple buttons that let people filter a page.

What is the conventional way to detect a button click in Angular and set the value of `$scope.filter_value` to the value of the button?

Should I be attaching `ng-click` to everything, or is there a better way?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9u1aqq24/

**HTML**

```
<main ng-app="myApp">
    <section ng-controller="myController">
        <h4>Filter by Role</h4>
        <div class="btn-group" ng-click="???">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="frontend developer" ng-click="console.log('CLICKED');">
                Frontend
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="backend developer">
                Backend
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="full stack developer">
                Full Stack
            </button>
        </div>
        <h4>Filter value</h4>
        <p>{{filter}}</p>
    </section>
</main>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.filter = null;  
}]);
```

Comment: added code to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-click` is a natural way of handling clicks in Angular. However, for your problem you might consider radio- or checkbox- buttons. You can find such components for example in [Angular-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons).

Comment: Ok so Angular-bootstrap is awesome - but even if I'm using the button group from it, it just updates the $scope.myModel. How can I have that kick off new events like $http (because I need to go get new data from the server)?

Comment: `$scope.$watch('myModel', function(){ /* $http ... */ });`

Answer (score 1):

Use just `ng-click="somefunction(parametr)"`

and after that in your controller

```
$scope.somefunction = function(parametr)
{
....
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setFilter = function(type) {
    // you can put all your logic here ($http.get.. or whatever)
    $scope.filter = type;



  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <h4>Filter by Role</h4>

    <div class="btn-group" ng-click="???">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="frontend developer" ng-click="setFilter('frontend developer')">Frontend</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="backend developer" ng-click="setFilter('backend developer')">Backend</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="full stack developer" ng-click="setFilter('full stack developer')">Full Stack</button>
    </div>
    <h4>Filter value</h4>

    <p>{{filter}}</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setFilter = function(type) {
    // you can put all your logic here ($http.get.. or whatever)
    $scope.filter = type;



  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <h4>Filter by Role</h4>

    <div class="btn-group" ng-click="???">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="frontend developer" ng-click="setFilter('frontend developer')">Frontend</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="backend developer" ng-click="setFilter('backend developer')">Backend</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-role="full stack developer" ng-click="setFilter('full stack developer')">Full Stack</button>
    </div>
    <h4>Filter value</h4>

    <p>{{filter}}</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer contains only code. It would be better if you could add some description of what it does and how. Can you please [edit] your answer and add it? Thank you!